# IBM data studio 4 - how to open a new sql script editor?

Tags: ibm-data-studio

I have to use IBM Data studio 4 and for the life of me I cannot figure how to open another SQL script editor window. Luckily it opens with one, but then I am constrained to that single window.

I don't want to go thru the trouble of having a project etc, just open another script and write a few statements.

PS: I know of a workaround of right-clicking an object in the connection tree and using Data/New Select Script, but that is a PITA as I have to open Table/View trees and point at one of the objects, and of course I am not always there (on the SP/Functions tree for instance) and it takes a while for the tree to open all objects.

Comment: Create a new `.sql` file or open an existing file with the SQL editor (right-click, **Open With...**).

Comment: Is there no other way?

Comment: Realistically, how many different ways of opening a file do you think there should be?

Comment: Realistically, I should be able to hit Ctrl-N and be done :) but Eclipse team believes different.

Comment: That proposes to create a new project with tons of different options, but I do not see a SQL window among them.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Datastudio 4.1.0.0 - New SQL Script]

Click the icon above....
That's the easiest way!